# Why answer is not found?

Tags: support

I try to use search panel and makeup [next query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3A4632019++perl_unicode): `infavorites:4632019`  `perl_unicode`. But nothing is found.

however the [query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3A4632019+utf-8): `infavorites:4632019` `utf-8` founds the [question I want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6163129/4632019)

Why first query does not found my question?
[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that `infavourites:` restricts the search to the question itself?

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation for infavorites](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) says

> infavorites:mine (or any user id) returns only questions that you (or the user whose id you entered) have favorited.

So it restricts searching to question text and while utf-8 occurs in the question, perl_unicode only occurs in an answer.

Comment: I have supposed that when I put something into favorites. like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default/ I put all: question and answers (there is no option to put into favorite target answer). So is there option to also check answers for favorite questions?

Comment: You'd need to write or find a [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) query to do that.

Comment: @ Robert Longson: link does not work

Comment: Have raised https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344277/sede-is-offline about that.